# Interacting with Firefox developer tools through Selenium Webdriver (JS Binding) programatically

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium

By using the below lines, I am able to launch a Firefox browser window and also the performance tab (Shift+F5) of the developer tool..

```
driver.get("about:blank");
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('body')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.SHIFT+webdriver.Key.F5);
```

But not able to interact with the launched developer tool window. By interaction I mean, clicking on the elements inside it... Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Developer tools window is not a part of a DOM and hence you cannot control it with Selenium.

If you really need to control it, you can use another automation tools together with Selenium. For example [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Comment: Sikuli does control browsers.. but never seen any examples working with browser developer tools.. Are there any online examples or videos?

Comment: Sikuli doesn't control browsers or any other specific applications. Sikuli just recognizes predefined visual patterns **anywhere** on the screen and simulates user actions (mouse movements and clicks, keyboard). You can start from http://www.sikuli.org/ to find documentation and examples. Shall you have any specific questions, please ask them on https://launchpad.net/sikuli.